# How to disable Notification Sounds on per-app basis?

Tags: applications, notifications, audio

I have an news app which gives me the option to get informed via push notification. I would like to receive this notification but I don't want it to make a notification sound. However the app doesn't allow me to choose a custom sound. Is there any other way to make it silent?

I do NOT want to disable the notification!

€dit: I'm on Android 4.2.2 ParanoidAndroid on Nexus 4

Answer (score 5):

I do not believe there is a built-in way to do this. I highly recommend the [light flow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflow) application which let's you customize light, sound and notifications on a per-app basis.

Comment: It seems it can not directly override the settings only if I can disable notification sounds in the app

Comment: Yes, Light-Flow only allows a custom tone, but it can't suppress the sound of the app, so this doesn't work.. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: Darn! Which application are you using?

Comment: ZDFheute (german APP), I contacted them, maybe they will include this feature in the future

Answer (score 2):

Andriod: doesn't offer this as a built in function. If the application doesn't offer the ability to turn off the sound, you're stuck: LightFlow cannot fix it. (as of Android 6.0: Marshmallow)

You either disable all notifications from the app (OS can do this), turn off all sounds from your device (OS can do this), or you're stuck with the app playing sounds.

Hey Andriod team: learn from Apple, which does offer sound-control for notifications on a per-app basis. (hint, hint :)

Comment: Last I checked, you can definitely change ringtone for apps notification on Android and it's much better than iOS. On Android, you would need to configure individual app settings for notification.

Comment: @anonymous coward: On my Samsung Galaxy S7, the exhaustive list of options, per app, is 'allow notifications', 'set as priority', 'preview in popups' and 'hide on lock screen.' Do you have a rooted device? That would motivate me to root mine